# How do I stop argparser from printing default search?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, youtube-data-api

Link to my code: https://pastebin.com/y4zLD2Dp
The imports that have not been used are going to be used as I progress through my project, I just like to have all imports I need ready to go. The goal for this program will be a youtube video downloader into mp3 format first. This is my first big project to my standards, only been coding for just over 2 months.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import sqlite3
import argparse
import sys
from selenium import webdriver


from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser

#To get a developer key visit https://console.developers.google.com.
DEVELOPER_KEY = ""
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

'''Searches for results on youtube and stores them in the database.'''
def yt_search(options):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search = youtube.search().list(q=options.q, part="id,snippet", 
                         maxResults=options.max_results).execute()

    video_id = []

    #Add results to a list and print them.
    for result in search.get("items", []):
        if result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            video_id.append("%s (%s)" % (result["snippet"]["title"],
                                    result["id"]["videoId"]))
        else:
            continue
    print("Videos:\n", "\n".join(video_id), "\n")

def download(args):
    print(args)  

"""Arguments for the program."""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description= "This program searches for 
          Youtube links and allows you to download songs from said list. " +
                                 "Please remember to be specific in your 
                                           searches for best results.")

    parser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default="Aeryes")
    parser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=25)

    parser.add_argument("--d", type=download, help="Download a video from 
                        search results.")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        parser.parse_args(['--help'])
        sys.exit(1)

    try:
        yt_search(args)
    except HttpError:
        print("HTTP error")
```

The problem that I am having is that upon running the --d cmd in the CLI it works and prints the arg as expected (This is just a test to see that functions are working with the parser) but after it prints a list of default youtube links from --q default which I do not want it to do. How do I stop this from happening. Should I use subparser or is there something that I am missing?

If anyone has good resources for argparser module other than official doc support please share.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the reason your code is behaving the way you describe, but have a look at the `argparse` documentation. I don't believe `type=download` is valid and might be causing strange behavior. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

Comment: I actually discovered the issue. I am passing all of the args through download not just args.d.

Comment: Disregard still not working